# Tooling API - Enable/Disable Parallel Test Execution?

Tags: apex, unit-test, tooling-api

I am creating a tool related test class execution scheduler.

Does Salesforce provide any way for the `Tooling API` to enable or disable `Parallel Test Execution`?

I want to set this setting by `Apex` and run every test classes one by one even after someone has changed the setting manually.

[image: Disable Parallel Apex Testing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically to your question on "Disable Parallel Apex Testing". No, I don't believe there is currently an official method in the Tooling API that exposes this setting.

That said, with Salesforce DX Scratch orgs we are being told that it will be possible to fully configure the org from a config file. That would imply a way to toggle all these otherwise unexposed settings.

**Update: (via [@bufuda](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155502/tooling-api-enable-disable-parallel-test-execution/155553?noredirect=1#comment482381_155553))** The [ApexSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_apexsettings.htm) for a scratch org now include a `enableDisableParallelApexTesting` setting that:

> Indicates whether Apex tests are serially executed (true) or not (false). The default value is false.

There is an article from Bob Buzzard on doing a [deploy to update the setting](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2019/09/parallel-apex-unit-tests-and-salesforce.html) after the org has been created. Note that this is via the Metadata rather than Tooling API.

---

Alternative example of doing this in vscode using a dedicated metadata file.

Path: `force-app\main\default\settings\Apex.settings-meta.xml`

Metadata file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <enableDoNotEmailDebugLog>true</enableDoNotEmailDebugLog>
   <enableDisableParallelApexTesting>true</enableDisableParallelApexTesting>
   <enableCompileOnDeploy>false</enableCompileOnDeploy>
</ApexSettings>
```

Then push this to the org to have the changes reflected.

---

If you want to go with the unsupported route there you can use the Chrome developer tools to see exactly how that setup page works.

> **Request URL:**https://abc.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/test/ApexTestQueueServlet
> **Request Method:** POST

> **Form Data**
> **action:** SET_OPTIONS
> **onlyStoreAggregateCoverage:** false
> **disableParallelApexTesting:** true
> **testAutonumber:** false

You could quite easily replicate that POST request (including the sid cookie). If you do so, know that it could break at any point as it isn't an official API.

Comment: Do we know a GA date for scratch orgs? They're not available yet, right?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Last I heard they were aiming for GA end of 2017 or early 2018. With a public beta before that. Of course, those dates could all change.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger for such a great descriptive answer.

I raised a case regarding same to salesforce.com support team and they told that this API is not available for now.

Comment: This option is now available for scratch orgs in the 'settings' portion of the scratch definition file. Specifically, enableDisableParallelApexTesting: true https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_apexsettings.htm

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it would help you to look at the `Force.com Tooling API` documentation, specifically on **[REST Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm)**. There are some URIs listed that look useful to you:

- `/runTestsSynchronous/`
- `/runTestsAsynchronous/`

There is a lot of detail in the documentation around these resources, too much to quote fully here. But they seem to provide an avenue to achieve what you are looking for.